# What is the use of following parameter in the following code?

Tags: python

I am learning python, coming from Java background. For starters I am doing it on Coursera. While solving practice questions I came across this particular code

```
import simplegui

message = "Welcome!"

# Handler for mouse click
def click():
    global message
    message = "Good job!"

# Handler to draw on canvas
def draw(canvas):
    canvas.draw_text(message, [50,112], 36, "Red")

# Create a frame and assign callbacks to event handlers
frame = simplegui.create_frame("Home", 300, 200)
frame.add_button("Click me", click)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)

# Start the frame animation
frame.start()
```

Now my question is regarding this particular method

```
 def draw(canvas):
    canvas.draw_text(message, [50,112], 36, "Red")
```

Here in this method why exactly do I need to use that particular parameter 'canvas'. Why I cannot do it simple like

```
 def draw():
    canvas.draw_text(message, [50,112], 36, "Red")
```

Because when you look at from where this method is called

```
frame.set_draw_handler(draw)
```

I am anyway not passing any parameter. So type of parameter is not there . Or is it that when i call it from method set_draw_handler(). Compiler automatically assumes that it is of type canvas.

Thank you 
:)

Comment: Python is dynamically typed, so the compiler does not assume type.

Comment: @EthanK yes exactly but then why do I need to use the param when I am not passing it in the method call in first place ?

Comment: You don't have to.

Comment: Python is an interpreted language. Additionally, functions are first-class objects. You are passing the draw function to set_draw_handler.

Comment: But the compiler tells me I have not defined it when I try to do it without param, so like java int i =0; Do I define it globally ?

Comment: You can call function `draw` without parameter `canvas` in case if your function was defined in same module (namespace) were `canvas` was instantiated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not passing in a call to the draw function, you're passing in the function itself. This is a callback: you give the library a function, and the library calls it when it needs to do something (in this case, when it needs to redraw the window). In order for your callback to be able to work, it needs some input from the library, in the form of the `canvas` parameter, so the library passes that in when it calls your function.

Comment: So you mean to say the parameter passing is handled internally ?Can I achieve the same by declaring canvas globally and not as param function like in java int i =0 ??

Comment: @Pritish No, `canvas` isn't yours to declare, it comes from the library. `frame.set_draw_handler(draw)` says "when you need to draw `frame`, call `draw`, passing in the canvas associated with `frame` so that `draw` knows where to draw".